# Flower identification (Singapore, April)

Tags: botany, species-identification

I saw some flowers growing by the roadside today, and was wondering about the species of this plant.

[image]

The plant also appeared to be fruiting, and it produced small fruits that formed small clusters.

[image]

Comment: Looks it belong to subfamily Mimosoideae under family Fabaceae

Comment: the long red rays seems their stamen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called "Red Powder Puff" or botanically *[Calliandra haematocephala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calliandra_haematocephala)*. See the images (from the Wikipedia article):

[image]

What you identified as the fruit appears to be the buds:

[image]

Some more information can be found [here](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=a493).